# User Profile Synchronization - not pulling details from Active Directory

Tags: 2013, user-profile-property

My SharePoint Server 2013 site is creating a Profile for new logged-on users however it is not pulling properties from Active directory for anything beyond their name and email. For instance I want also their Title or Department. It did at one time but has since stopped importing. It is however still pulling correct data from my BDC - so something is running correctly. The new users are not being added to the User Information List.

I have User Profile Synchronization set up and both the User Profile Service and User Profile Synchronization service is green "Started" status.

Running `stsadm.exe o-sync -listolddatabases 0` shows that my content databases have all been synchronized recently.

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\15.0\Synchronization Service\UIShell\miisclient.exe`  shows regular Adds, Deletes and Updates, with no errors, however if I look at Management Agent and get Properties on ILMMA the only populated field is the FIM Service base address: which is set to http://localhost:5725. Is that typical? I can not start the miisclient.exe utility on my web server, only on my application server.

I have noticed that the two Forefront Identity Management services are only started on my application server, not on my web server. (From comments I now know that this is correct)

**Should I restart my User Profile Synchronization Service? Are there any risks to restarting User Profile Synchronization Service, or a reference to specific steps I should follow to do that without losing existing User Profile data? We have added user photos and people have added "About Me" text, and I wouldn't want to loose all of that.**

Comment: What auth method are you using for SharePoint? Windows, SAML, or FBA? The FIM services only run on the server that is running the UPSS. Other servers do not run these services.

Comment: SharePoint Sync service only run on the server where you configured it, and it is configured on single server. So you only get the MIIS client on the server where UPA Sync Provisioned. restart is ok but give more detail about your configuration settings?

Comment: Trevor, We are using Windows authentication. The UPSS is "Started" on the same server that the FIM is running. So that looks correct. Thanks for that. Do I have it right that the ILMMA is related to the User Profile Synch? And if so, does that setup (in question) look right? I'm starting to think that perhaps UPSS is running just fine, and maybe there's a problem with the property mappings - but like I say, at one time they worked.

Answer (score -2):

Should it be running on both? - **Yes**

If so, I understand I should probably restart my User Profile Synchronization Service. - **Yes**

Are there any risks to that, or a reference to specific steps I should follow to do that without loosing existing User Profile data? - **You will need to configure it aging from scratch**

Please check here.

[Step by Step: Active Directory Import for SharePoint 2013](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/meacoex/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013/)

[Configure profile synchronization by using SharePoint Active Directory Import in SharePoint Server 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/jj219646.aspx)

Comment: She mentioned she is using the User Profile Sync and NOT ADI and you are referencing her to wrong direction.

Comment: Read First two line Dude.

Comment: She already mentioned here that "My SharePoint Server 2013 site is creating a Profile for new logged-on users however it is not pulling properties from Active directory for anything beyond their name and email. For instance I want also their Title or Department."

Comment: Please put comment if you do have the reason to downvote the answer. I will be really happy.

Comment: Really, that tells you that she is using ADI...I think, it is better if you completely understand the question and respond it... what you responded about her question A and B? that applied to upa sync.

Comment: FIM services only run on the server running UPSS, so your first answer is wrong. As for UPSS, doesn't sound like there is a need to restart it from the information provided. Your links reference ADI and not UPSS.

Comment: Thanks guys to correct me. I don't feel i am wrong but you said that and i liked it. I can get better idea from it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not using ADI. I am using UPSS. My UPSS has two synchronization connections. One for Active Directory and one for another Business Data Connection